# Git pull with reference libraries the path keeps changing

Tags: eclipse, git, jar

I am working on the same project with another person, and we sync our work using Git. Whenever we do a `git push` / `git pull` the paths to our external libraries are updated with paths that are valid only for the other person's machine. The paths are defined here:

[image]

I have nothing in my `.gitignore` file. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is in your `.gitignore`?

Comment: i dont have anything in .gitignore wht is it and how to add it to my repository

Answer (score 0):

You have committed some files to your Git repo that are designed to be user-specific, and should not have been committed.

Add a `.gitignore` file containing at least the following:

```
.metadata
.classpath
```

Or better, import one from e.g. [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/api/eclipse).

To remove the files you have already committed to the repo:

```
git rm --cached -r .metadata
git rm --cached MyProject/.classpath
```

and commit the changes (including your `.gitignore`).

The `git rm` commands will remove the files from the repo, but not from your working directory, so Eclipse can still find them. However, the files will be deleted from the working directory of anyone else who pulls this commit. To work around this, after the other devs have pulled your changes, you can have them do e.g.:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- MyProject/.classpath
git checkout HEAD^ -- .metadata

# Unstage the files, if necessary.
git reset HEAD -- MyProject/.classpath
git reset HEAD -- .metadata
```

After all of this, you should be able to modify those paths per-user, and the changes will not be tracked by Git.

Answer (score 0):

Group the Selenium jars into a **User Library** that you can reference from the `.classpath` file, but define differently on each machine. It adds a layer of indirection that you seem to need. http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm?cp=1_4_2_0_1_1